# h:dataTable content displayed on .jsf page load,instead of commandLink click only

Tags: ajax, jsf, datatable

Looks like simple,but doesn't work)

When .jsf page is loaded ,values from DB is shown.
dao impl chunk:

```
public List<Product> getProducts() {
    return getHibernateTemplate().find("from Product");

}
```

managed bean chunk:

```
public List<Product> getProducts() {
    return this.getProductManager().getProducts();
}
```

I intented,that `f:ajax` does this work by click only:

```
         <h:form>

            <h:commandLink value="show" action="nothing">
                <f:ajax render="pr"/>
            </h:commandLink>


            <h:dataTable var="product" id="pr" value="#{showProducts.products}">
                  <h:column>#{product.name}</h:column>
            </h:dataTable>

         </h:form>
```

And the data is visible on page,when it's loaded.
With Firebug I can see,that data is refreshed by click, so ajax does it's work.

Do I need additional attributes for `h:dataTable` element for table content to be displayed on click only?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hide the datatable on initial request and let the commandlink toggle a boolean where the datatable's `rendered` attribute is depending on.

Facelets:

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandLink value="show" action="#{showProducts.toggleShow}">
        <f:ajax render="products"/>
    </h:commandLink>
    <h:panelGroup id="products">
        <h:dataTable var="product" value="#{showProducts.products}" rendered="#{!showProducts.show}">
            <h:column>#{product.name}</h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

Bean:

```
private boolean show;

public void toggleShow() {
    show = !show; // Or just show = true;
}

public boolean isShow() {
    return show;
}
```

---

That said, it's not the best practice to run expensive business/database logic inside a getter. A getter can be called more than once in bean's life. Rather do this job in bean's constructor or `@PostConstruct` method.

```
private List<Product> products;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    products = this.getProductManager().getProducts();
}

public List<Product> getProducts() {
    return products;
}
```

Or if it actually needs to be lazily loaded, then rather do so:

```
private List<Product> products;

public List<Product> getProducts() {
    if (products == null) {
        products = this.getProductManager().getProducts();
    }
    return products;
}
```

Comment: yes, it came to me also that "rendered" should be used.I've got an error unfortunetely:"Method must have signature "String method()" but has signature "void method()" for toggleShow method call

Comment: Is it Eclipse with its worthless EL validator again? Just ignore and run it. If it's bothering you, either disable EL validator or fix it as per the error message and let it return `null`.

Comment: yes,BalusC,you are correct,it's Eclipses. Strange alert got:malformedXML: During update: j_idt5:products not found

Comment: use case is: 1.load page - got link only(that  is ok);2.click on link-got alert above;3.click refresh - got datatatle content

Comment: perhaps,should load table on page,but hide it,because initially,it doesn't present on the page at all

Comment: You did put the `id` on a `h:panelGroup` (or some parent element) and the `rendered` attribute on the nested `h:dataTable` as in my example, right? If you put the `id` on a component which is not rendered to the view, then Ajax simply cannot find anything in the HTML DOM tree to update :)

Comment: dummy error! BalusC,thank you, i really didn't add pannelGroup.Didn't mind it's significant